# Mongoose: Filter doc and manipulate nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an image schema that has a reference to a category schema and a nested array that contains an object with two fields (user, createdAt)

I am trying to query the schema by a category and add two custom fields to each image in my query.

Here is the solution with virtual fields:

**totalLikes**: Count of all nested attributes

```
schema.virtual("totalLikes").get(function() {
  return this.likes.length;
});
```

**canLike**: Check if user with id "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1" is included in the nested array. If user is included it should return false otherwise true

```
schema.virtual("canLike").get(function() {
  return !this.likes.find(like => {
    return like.user === "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1";
  });
});
```

In sql it would be a simple SUBQUERY but I can't get it working in Mongoose.

Schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const model = new mongoose.Schema(
{
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category"
  },
  likes: [{
    user: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  }]
})
```

here is a sample document:

```
[{
    category:5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d,
    likes: [
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    category:5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d,
    likes: [
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1dw223332",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        },
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1d8498933",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here is how it should look like:

```
 [{
    category:5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d,
    likes: [
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        }
    ],
    totalLikes: 1,
    canLike: false
},

 {
    category:5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d,
    likes: [
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1dw223332",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        },
        {
        _id: "5c90a4c79906507dac54e764",
        user: "5c8f9e676ed4356b1d8498933",
        createdAt:"2019-03-19T08:13:59.250+00:00"
        }
    ],
    totalLikes: 2,
    canLike: true
 }]
```

Here is what I tried:

Resolver:

1) Tried in Mongoose call -  Fails

```
const resources = await model.aggregate([
      { $match: {category: "5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d"},
      $addFields: {
        totalLikes: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$likes",
              as: "el",
              cond: "$$el.user"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      $addFields: {
        canLike: {
            $match: {
              'likes.user':"5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1"
            }              
        }
      }
    }
      ])
```

2) Tried to change it after db call - works but not preferred solution

```
model.where({ competition: "5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d"  }).exec(function (err, records) {


    resources = records.map(resource => {

    resource.likes = resource.likes ? resource.likes: []

    const included = resource.likes.find(like => {
      return like.user === "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1";
    });

    resource.set('totalLikes', resource.likes.length, {strict: false});
    resource.set('canLike', !included, {strict: false});

   return resource
  });
})
```

Does anyone know how I can do it at runtime? THX

Comment: What does a document actually look like and what are you expecting as a result? The `cond` on your `$filter` is a `Boolean` and you are only giving it a "string" as best I can see from the schema. So it's really not clear what you want without sample data and an expected result. Please add them

Comment: Hi, added sample document and expected result to my post :-)

Comment: regarding the filter: I thought that it would behave similar to javascript... variable would be true if it is not null or false.....

Comment: Yeah, but what's the point? Why is it that like count and why is canLiked `true/false`. Showing one element in an array also is not helping. Show a couple of elements and explain the rules of when things are counted and what `canLiked` even means. Compare to the supplied user parameter? Compared to another value in the document? Another collection? We don't know, because you are not telling us. Edit your question to make those things better.

Comment: have you seen my second try: let resources = await model.where({ category: "5c90a0777952597cda9e9c8d"  }).map(resource => {

        const included = resource.likes.find(like => {
          return like.user === "5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1";
        });
        return {
          ...resource,
          totalLikes: resource.likes.length,
          canLike: !included
        };
      });

Comment: I see the code, but I don't see how it correlates to your expected result. In all fairness if the code was correct you would not be asking the question. You know it's not right, and therefore it's not a guide to explaining what you want. Just explain in words [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55237468/edit). Then people will understand what you want to happen and why they come out to the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it using aggregate

```
Model.aggregate()
.addFields({ // map likes so that it can result to array of ids
    likesMap: {
        $map: {
            input: "$likes",
            as: "like",
            in: "$$like.user"
        }
    }   
})
.addFields({ // check if the id is present in likesMap
    canLike: {
        $cond: [
            {
                $in: ["5c8f9e676ed4356b1de3eaa1", "$likesMap"]
            },
            true,
            false
        ]
    },
    totalLikes: {
        $size: "$likes"
    }
})
.project({ // remove likesMap
    likesMap: 0,
})
```